# android:map loading prob

Tags: android, maps

I have made an app in which i am using google maps, maps are  loading in india on gprs, wifi etc and not wrking on some android devices in swiss having gprs and 3g internet connection even the buld is same.
What could be the problem?Can anyone help me over this?
thanks